Removing interior shutters
My partner and I just bought a townhouse, and one thing we don't like about it is the window treatments: all the windows and patio doors have thick shutters ("plantation shutters") on them, with slats about 3" wide, which we both find visually disruptive and bulky-looking. Since we're in the Pacific Northwest, keeping sunlight out is rarely the intent.
Ideally, we'd like to quickly remove them and have the whole interior repainted before we move in (we'll probably have 10 days between taking possession and when we have to leave our current place. So we'd like to remove the shutters as quickly as possible before the painters come, but don't know how easy this will be what it will entail. We think they're probably Levolor blinds like these, with inward-folding doors for the patios (which already have sliding glass doors. Unfortunately we don't currently have access to the house to check the specifics. But they looked like they were screwed into the frames.
How big a job will it be to pull them out, and how much mess will it leave behind?

You should get moving and get quotes. If you are planning to do it yourself and they are outside, whats the hurry - have a go at one. To get a better response you need to post a photo.

If they're like what you've shown us, removing them should be easy. Remove the hinges, fill the screw holes, and paint. You may be able to get away with just putting a dab of paint over the filler; at worst, you'd be repainting just the frame, not the whole wall.

Possibly sand the filler before paint, depending on the quality of your work.

We're going to be hiring painters to do all the interior walls anyhow, so we just want to get these off entirely before we have that done. If all it will leave behind is screw holes, that's great, that will be relatively manageable.

There might go be some unpainted wood under the hinges. Again, should be easy to clean up. Dismount one and check...

The hinges might also be mortised in. In which case, you might need to fill that mortise before refinishing the surface. Usually that's just a matter of dropping a small filler piece into the opening. Again, removing one hinge should be enough to tell you what you are dealing with and let you plan for the others.
